# YouTube Player IFrame API, hooking event for currentTime

Tags: youtube-api, angular

I'm aware of the `player.GetCurrentTime()` method. For my context, it would be better to hook this changing value as an event as to having to poll for it.

It's an angular2/typescript use. I'm hooking three other events that get hooked correctly.  In the following, the first three subscriptions work, while the currentTime-changed does not. I've also tried currentTime-changed.

```js
        this._ytPlayer.addEventListener("onReady", e=> this.onPlayerReady(e)) ;
        this._ytPlayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', e => this.onStateChanged(e));
        this._ytPlayer.addEventListener('onError', e => this.onError(e));

        this._ytPlayer.addEventListener('currentTime-change', e => this.onCurrentTimeChanged(e));
```

Is it possible to hook the property change on the IFrame api and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, changes in the current time of a video are not exposed via the iframe API. Your only option would be to set up your own little polling interval (using setInterval or requestAnimationFrame) that will query the api for currentTime every so often (maybe 10 times a second, as the API will not update the time more often than that) and update a running variable. You could then watch that variable for changes to get your hooks to run.